# Executing a stored procedure doesn't complete the whole logic inside it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to run this stored procedure, but it only runs the first command, although I'm able to run the script outside the stored procedure without any problems

```
exec GetStoreTransfers '010203','010304'
```

but it only returns the first command result:

```
output
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 file(s) copied.
NULL

(2 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

This is the stored procedure, but only the first command executes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStoreTransfers] 
    (@fromdate nvarchar(8),
     @todate nvarchar(8))
AS
    DECLARE @from nvarchar(8)
    DECLARE @to nvarchar(8)
    DECLARE @to_ nvarchar(16)
    DECLARE @from_ nvarchar(16)
    DECLARE @cmdcopy nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @command nvarchar(max)

    SET @from = @fromdate
    SET @to = @todate
 
    SET @from_ = LEFT(CONVERT(char(16), CAST(@from AS date), 105), 5)
    SET @to_ = LEFT(CONVERT(char(16), CAST(@to AS date), 105), 5)

    SELECT @cmdcopy = ''/* some cmd commands*/
  
    SELECT @command = ''/* some T-SQL commands*/

    exec xp_cmdshell @cmdcopy
    exec sp_executesql @command
```

The result of the entire query without using a stored procedure is as follows

```
  output
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1 file(s) copied.
NULL

(2 row(s) affected)

(23654 row(s) affected)
```

Please  help me to overcome this problem, I don't want to use a SQL Job, it's an easier workaround but is not what I want.

UPDATE:

The problem was that the date format was invalid in `@fromdate` and `@todate`, which made the query returns NULL, I passed the correct parameter and everything worked as it should.

Comment: Do you mean it only runs the first command within `/*A Set of commands*/` ? You should post the first two at least.

Comment: No one can debug code that cannot be seem. YOU cannot debug code (even though you have the complete source and the associated execute statement) without seeing the actual  tsql your procedure generates BEFORE attempting to execute it.

Comment: As I said, there are no errors in the code, it runs fine without using it in a proc, but when I try to run this stored procedure, it only executes the xp_cmdshell command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I used parameter values that makes the result return nulls, which affects the whole logic of the stored procedure, I think a better approach is to print a message if there's no data returned, this would make the execution less confusing and more informative, let's say it would be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStoreTransfers] 
    (@fromdate nvarchar(8),
     @todate nvarchar(8))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @from nvarchar(8)
    DECLARE @to nvarchar(8)
    DECLARE @to_ nvarchar(16)
    DECLARE @from_ nvarchar(16)
    DECLARE @cmdcopy nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @command nvarchar(max)

    SET @from = @fromdate
    SET @to = @todate
 
    SET @from_ = LEFT(CONVERT(char(16), CAST(@from AS date), 105), 5)
    SET @to_ = LEFT(CONVERT(char(16), CAST(@to AS date), 105), 5)

    SELECT @cmdcopy = ''/* some cmd commands*/
  
    SELECT @command = ''/* some T-SQL commands*/

    IF @cmdcopy IS NULL OR @command ISNULL
      PRINT ('WARNING!, some parameter(s) has an invalid value, please check')

    exec xp_cmdshell @cmdcopy
    exec sp_executesql @command
 
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
     PRINT ('If the proc did not execute properly, please check the queries below:')

 PRINT @cmdcopy
 PRINT @command

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `begin`/`end` block:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[GetStoreTransfers] (
    @fromdate nvarchar(8),
    @todate nvarchar(8)
) as
begin
    declare @from nvarchar(8)
    declare @to nvarchar(8)
    declare @to_ nvarchar(16)
    declare @from_ nvarchar(16)
    declare @cmdcopy nvarchar(1000)
    declare @command nvarchar(max)

    set @from=@fromdate
    set @to=@todate

    set @from_=left(convert(char(16),cast(@from as date),105),5)
    set @to_=left(convert(char(16),cast(@to as date),105),5)

    select @cmdcopy = /*A specific String*/

    select @command=/*A Set of commands*/

    exec xp_cmdshell @cmdcopy

    exec sp_executesql @command    
end;
```

Comment: No Change Happened, It only executed the first command 
exec xp_cmdshell @cmdcopy

Comment: The `BEGIN/END` block  is just eye candy AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman for helping, I've been creating successful procs since

Answer (score 1):

You should try a TRY/CATCH block, and also, try to capture xp_cmdshell result:

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @Error    INT;

    select @cmdcopy = /*A specific String*/

    select @command=/*A Set of commands*/

    exec @Error = xp_cmdshell @cmdcopy

    IF(@Error <> 0)
        /*Do some stuff*/
    END

    exec @Error = sp_executesql @command 

    IF(@Error <> 0)
        /*Do some stuff*/
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT(ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH
```

Give it a try and let us know :)

Regards!

Comment: As I said, there are no errors in the code, it runs fine without using it in a proc, but when I try to run this stored procedure, it only executes the xp_cmdshell command

Comment: Yes, I know, that is why I'd try to see whats happening inside the SP. I'd compare the return values from xp_cmdshell both in the SP and from query window to look up for different results, maybe you've got a permissions issue, let me know :)

Comment: It turns out when I was executing the proc, I used invalid parameters that are not available in the tables I was trying to get data from, now it works fine after changing the "fromdate" and "todate" parameters.

Comment: Good catch, did you manage to get the errors with the TRY block? Regards!

Comment: actually I didn't use the TRY block, I simply executed the query and it returned no data, so I figured it's because I ran the query before with different parameters than what I used with the stored procedure. anyway, Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Awsome! Regards!